# Query json for existing value in list of values

Tags: jquery, sql, json

I've got (simplified) the following json in my Azure Sql Database:

```
{
    "Basket": "Test",
    "Products": [
        { "Id": 1, "Name": "Apple" },
        { "Id": 2, "Name": "Pear" },
        { "Id": 3, "Name": "Coconut" },
    ]
}
```

I would like to query a table filled with baskets like the above.

```
CREATE TABLE [Baskets] (
  [id] [int] NOT NULL,
  [json] [varchar](max) NOT NULL
)
```

Let's say I want write a query to select only the baskets containing a coconut. How would one go about this?

I can write a query like below only there are more products possible...

```
SELECT 
  Id, 
  Json 
FROM 
  Baskets
WHERE 
  JSON_VALUE(json, '$.Products[0].Id' = '3'
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer (for future reference) is to use the [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

```
SELECT 
  Id, 
  Json 
FROM 
  Baskets
WHERE 
  'Coconut' = in (
    select Name from OPENJSON(json, '$.Products') 
    with (Name nvarchar(30) '$.Name')
  )
```